# How to display data from gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I simply added grid view and added columns and gave headertext
But when i run the application i am not able to see any grid,,atleast i should see grid column names

Do i need to do any thing more

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accepted if it works for you ...

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have everything wired up properly and are assigning a `DataSource` and doing a `DataBind()`.  Once you have verified that these two things are happening then make sure that your DataSource is returning some type of result set with at least one item.

A `GridView` will not display anything at all unless there is at least 1 item in the result set.  If you bind to a `DataSet` or some type of object list and there are not items in it then the grid will no display at all.  Not even the headers.  In this case you should setup the `EmptyDataText` property to display something.

If not if this helps, please post your GridView markup and the code where you bind your grid and I'll see if I can figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

check aspx page code

```
<asp:MyGridView runat="server" DataKeyNames="pkey" AutoUpdateAfterCallBack="true"
            Width="100%"
            ID="grduser" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sr No." DataField="rownumber" ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="10px"
                    ItemStyle-Width="10px" />

                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="FirstName" DataField="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName"
                    ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="LoginName" DataField="LoginName" SortExpression="LoginName"
                    ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Email" DataField="Email" SortExpression="Email" ReadOnly="true"
                    HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Role" DataField="Role" SortExpression="Role" ReadOnly="true"
                    HeaderStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-Width="30px" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reportingto" DataField="Reportingto" SortExpression="Reportingto"
                    ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="120px" ItemStyle-Width="120px" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MobileNo" DataField="MobileNo" SortExpression="Mobile_no"
                    ReadOnly="true" HeaderStyle-Width="30px" ItemStyle-Width="30px" />

            </Columns>
        </asp:MyGridView>
```

Cs file code to bind grid

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = //get dataset form the database 
DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
this.grduser.DataSource = dv;
this.grdusers.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is as Kelsey says:

```
<emptydatatemplate>              
   No Data Found. 
</emptydatatemplate>
```

Other techniques:

1. Override the CreateChildControls (example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1003306.aspx)
2. Manually insert a row (example: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200722021652/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/11/tiptrick-show-header-and-footer-of-gridview-when-no-data.aspx))